# unauthorisedAccessException when writing to a file

Tags: c#

im very new to c# and am trying to write to a file but i get this error. Any suggestions?

```
    System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'C:\Users\tom\Desktop\theBeast\theBeast\bin\Debug' is denied.'
my code:

string hashedValue = Hash(hashed);
string Path = @"\Users\tom\Desktop\theBeast\theBeast\bin\Debug";

using (System.IO.StreamWriter Account = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Path, true))
{
     Account.WriteLine(Username + "," + hashedValue + ",User");
     System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Account Successfully Created");
}
```

Comment: I suggest you post your code.

Comment: Do you permissions to write to that directory?  If you try to create a new file there does it say you are denied, or say you need admin rights?

Comment: I'd expect Path variable to contain a path to a file rather than a folder: 
@"...\Debug\filename.txt"

Comment: @Artem is right, without a name for the file you won't get far.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take a file path to write something and close stream to save the file.
for you try this :

```
string hashedValue = Hash(hashed);
string Path = @"\Users\tom\Desktop\theBeast\theBeast\bin\Debug\test.txt";

using ( System.IO.StreamWriter Account = new System.IO.StreamWriter( Path , true ) )
            {
                Account.WriteLine( Username + "," + hashedValue + ",User" );
                Account.Close();
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show( "Account Successfully Created" );
            }
```